# Directional Anova Post-Hoc Analysis in R

Tags: r, anova, biostatistics, tukey-hsd-test

prefacing this with the fact I have a concussion and may or may not be making sense/thinking clearly at the moment.
I'm working on rewriting an assignment that asks us to find significant differences between groups using ANOVA and then TukeyHSD as post-hoc analysis. When I originally did the analysis, I merely found that there were differences between groups and moved on; but apparently I am supposed to "specify the direction for each pairwise comparison". They're looking for the format of "food insecurity for males > females". My main question here is how do I do that? My understanding is that ANOVA checks if there is a difference between groups but does not give directional information. Should I be doing another analysis (which I don't think is the case) or am I missing something in the output?

I'm exploring using gender as a confounding factor for an insecurity score on a survey given to county residents. An Anova comparison showed a significant p-value, so I moved onto Tukey. But how am I supposed to figure out who has the larger insecurity score in the pairings from this? BTW The numbered groups are representative of a gender category (male, female, agender/non-binary)

```
TukeyHSD(aov(SHAPE_survey$Insecurity2~factor(SHAPE_survey$Gender3)))
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = SHAPE_survey$Insecurity2 ~ factor(SHAPE_survey$Gender3))

$`factor(SHAPE_survey$Gender3)`
          diff        lwr       upr     p adj
2-1 -0.1294355 -0.4685115 0.2096405 0.6435152
3-1  1.3269409  0.1882313 2.4656506 0.0173732
3-2  1.4563765  0.3369656 2.5757873 0.0065052
```

Comment: Welcome to CV. This being an 'assignment', might it need a [`self-study`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study) tag? To help you on your way: what does each of the columns in your function's output represent?

Comment: You can also look at the estimated marginal means or raw means for each gender together with your output.